# rewrite .htaccess to remove .php GET method

Tags: .htaccess, get

I am planning on removing the .php extension from my webpages. I already have the code for the .htaccess file I want to use;

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

Before I start editing the file I have one question;

When I do this, what happens to pages that use the GET method? For example index.php?mode=logout

Does this still work? If not, is there a workaround?

Comment: It won't unless there is a query with the parameters in the incoming URL. Example; `http://example.com/?mode=logout`. In those cases the incoming query will be appended automatically to the resource. Example: `RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php?mode=logout [NC,L]` No need for the `QSA` flag unless a new query is added in the rewrite rule. But, you should give some URL examples to be able to understand what you need. In all cases, though, the incoming URL must hold the parameters to be passed to the resource, including the name in this case.

Answer (score 0):

You can include [QSA](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/flags.html#flag_qsa) to keep query strings intact.

```
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L,QSA]
```

Comment: But do I have to edit my page? Because some pages require 2 variables through the GET method. For example the reset page; 
       reset.php?activation=$variable1&email=$variable2

What will this link look like? And do I have to edit the page to work with the new link?

Comment: You shouldn't need to edit your page. If it's already working by getting variables exclusively through GET, adding a rewrite with QSA should continue to work. It will rewrite `page/?var1=test&var2=test` to `page.php?var1=test&var2=test`.